# Make `column` use a single space as column separators in output

Tags: columns, text-formatting

```
$ echo 'a b' | column -t 
a  b
```

There are 2 spaces between `a` and `b` in the output. How can I make `column` use only one space for separation when possible?

EDIT 2: Changed data to include more cases

```
$ cat data 
1 2 b
20 12.5 something
300 12.8 as
600 16 asrgty
1200 4.9 srty
1800 33.5 sry
10000 1.5 sty
200000 1.5 sty
$ column -t < data
1       2     b
20      12.5  something
300     12.8  as
600     16    asrgty
1200    4.9   srty
1800    33.5  sry
10000   1.5   sty
200000  1.5   sty
$  column -t -s '' < data
1 2 b
20 12.5 something
300 12.8 as
600 16 asrgty
1200 4.9 srty
1800 33.5 sry
10000 1.5 sty
200000 1.5 sty
$ column -t -s ' ' < data
1       2     b
20      12.5  something
300     12.8  as
600     16    asrgty
1200    4.9   srty
1800    33.5  sry
10000   1.5   sty
200000  1.5   sty
$ column -t < data | sed -re 's/  / /g'
1    2   b
20   12.5 something
300   12.8 as
600   16  asrgty
1200  4.9  srty
1800  33.5 sry
10000  1.5  sty
200000 1.5  sty
$ column -t < data | sed -re 's/  / /'
1      2     b
20     12.5  something
300    12.8  as
600    16    asrgty
1200   4.9   srty
1800   33.5  sry
10000  1.5   sty
200000 1.5   sty
```

Expected

```
1      2    b
20     12.5 something
300    12.8 as
600    16   asrgty
1200   4.9  srty
1800   33.5 sry
10000  1.5  sty
200000 1.5  sty
```

---

Note:
Please don't give `sed` hacks that work for this specific case. Questions on SE should be useful to others and not limited to highly specific data formats.

Comment: Default output separator is two spaces so you could run: `echo 'a b' | column -t -o ' '`.

Comment: @don_crissti `column: invalid option -- 'o'`

Answer (score 5):

You can trim *only the last space character* in *any series of space characters;* like this:

```
sed 's/\( *\) /\1/g'
```

---

And since you always have at least two space chars in a row, this will always work to trim the splits out just as you wish:

#### INPUT:

```
column -t -s\ <<\COLS | sed 's/\( *\) /\1/g'
0 3.1415926535 s
00 3.141592653 so
000 3.14159265 som
0000 3.1415926 some
00000 3.141592 somet
000000 3.14159 someth
0000000 3.1415 somethi
00000000 3.141 somethin
000000000 3.14 something
COLS
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
0         3.1415926535 s
00        3.141592653  so
000       3.14159265   som
0000      3.1415926    some
00000     3.141592     somet
000000    3.14159      someth
0000000   3.1415       somethi
00000000  3.141        somethin
000000000 3.14         something
```

---

To really demonstrate how `sed` will honor the rule, we can append a couple copies of our columns end over end w/ each additional gaining a single space offset...

#### INPUT:

```
column -t <input | sed 's/.*/&  &   &/;s/\( *\) /\1/g'
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
0         3.1415926535 s 0         3.1415926535 s  0         3.1415926535 s
00        3.141592653  so 00        3.141592653  so  00        3.141592653  so
000       3.14159265   som 000       3.14159265   som  000       3.14159265   som
0000      3.1415926    some 0000      3.1415926    some  0000      3.1415926    some
00000     3.141592     somet 00000     3.141592     somet  00000     3.141592     somet
000000    3.14159      someth 000000    3.14159      someth  000000    3.14159      someth
0000000   3.1415       somethi 0000000   3.1415       somethi  0000000   3.1415       somethi
00000000  3.141        somethin 00000000  3.141        somethin  00000000  3.141        somethin
000000000 3.14         something 000000000 3.14         something  000000000 3.14         something
```

Comment: I edited the question to request for solutions that are not specific to my particular data format.

Comment: This is great. Can you provide a bit of an explanation as to how this `sed` substitution syntax works; so we all might adapt it to our own needs? Some bits are a bit beyond basic; like: `\( *\) `, `/\1/` & `/&  &   &/;`. Very interesting though, thanks.

Comment: @tjt263 - that's actually _basic_ stuff if you read the manual; it's called grouping and back-referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$ echo 'a b' | column -t -s ''
a b
```

From column manpage:

- `-t` Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default, or with the characters supplied using the -s option.  Useful for pretty-printing displays.
- `-s` Specify a set of characters to be used to delimit columns for the -t option.

After your edition, this command should work:

```
$ cat data | column -t | sed -r 's:  : :'
300  12.8
600  16.9
900  19.2
1200 24.9
1500 29.7
1800 33.5
```

A command for the last update (sorry mate, but is a `sed` command, can't see the way of doing only with `column`):

```
$ cat data | column -t | sed -r 's: ( [a-z,0-9]):\1:g'
1      2    b
20     12.5 something
300    12.8 as
600    16   asrgty
1200   4.9  srty
1800   33.5 sry
10000  1.5  sty
200000 1.5  sty
```

Comment: Its probably a good idea to adopt `-E` as a habit as that will be the official syntax if/when POSIX ever moves forward w/ their already *Accepted as Marked* bug report on adopting ERE. It is already supported for GNU and BSD `sed` versions - though GNU doesnt document it. That said, your ERE fails for any columns not beginning w/ a lowercase letter and/or numeric - and even that might fail depending on locale. Since `columns` works on a single delim char anyway, why not just `s/ \([^ ]\)/\1/g`?

Comment: The first one `echo 'a b' | column -t -s ''` does not work for me. If I put more spaces between `a` and `b` the output will have more spaces

Answer (score 1):

Addressing [user80551's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179314/make-column-use-a-single-space-as-column-separators-in-output/681014#comment298209_179314) under the question:

> @don_crissti `column: invalid option -- 'o'`

Maybe [don_crissti's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179314/make-column-use-a-single-space-as-column-separators-in-output/681014#comment298207_179314) example was cut off ...

> Default output separator is two spaces so you could run:
>
> ```
> echo 'a b' | column -t -o ' '
> ```

This worked:

```
echo 'a b' | column -t -o " "
```

For example 2:

```
column -t -o " " < data
```